# install homebrew forumula from someone else's branch

Tags: r, homebrew

I wanted to install a r forumla from a person's branch of homebrew-science

I follow the instructions on homebrew FAQ, but got the following errors.

```
brew install https://github.com/aeroevan/homebrew-science/blob/5b75b8833140d8f443d398d64825da9213b44d09/r.rb
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/r.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<!DOCTYPE html>
 ^
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/r.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<html>
 ^
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/r.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected '<'
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
     ^
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/r.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected '<'
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     ^
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/r.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                                              ^
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:47:in `require'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:47:in `klass'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:137:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:182:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:433:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `map'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:40:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:107:in `send'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:107
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you've used, https://github.com/aeroevan/homebrew-science/blob/5b75b8833140d8f443d398d64825da9213b44d09/r.rb, pretty clearly points to an HTML document, not a valid Ruby script. Click that link in your browser and you'll see. Instead use the URL to the **raw** file:

```
brew install https://raw2.github.com/aeroevan/homebrew-science/5b75b8833140d8f443d398d64825da9213b44d09/r.rb
```